# how to send an id="" to all socket in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a problem with nodejs and socket.io
I tried in other discussions in order to understand how to solve my problem , but I did not succeed .
I'm going to create a board with score and I created a simple counter in javascript . I want to convey to all who open the ' localhost address : port with nodejs advances counter
this is what I have made ​​so far

**tabellone.js**

```
    var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var http    = require('http').Server(app);
var io      = require('socket.io')(http)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.emit('some event', { for: 'everyone' });

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('contatore', function(){
   socket.broadcast.emit('contatore', contatore);
    });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

**index.html**

```
    <html>
<head>
  <title>tab</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<body>
<ul id="tab"></ul> 
  <form id="form">
   <p id="contatore">0</p>
   <button id="m" type="button" 
   onClick="javascript:contatore_su();"> + </button>
   <button type="button" 
   onClick="javascript:contatore_giu();"> - </button>
   </form>
 <script>
  var s=0;
  function contatore_su() {
   s=s+1;
   document.getElementById('contatore').innerHTML = s;
 }
 function contatore_giu() {
   s=s-1;
   document.getElementById('contatore').innerHTML = s;
 }
</script>
<script>
var socket=io();
 $('form').click(function(){
   socket.emit('conteggio', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('conteggio', function(msg){
    $('#tab').append($('<li>').test(msg));
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have previously created a chat by following what is written on socket.io but I can not convey to all connected sockets the advancement counter , thanks for the help
ps. Sorry for my english :')

Comment: What is the variable `contatore` in your node.js code. Where is it initialized and modified ?

Comment: Contatore is a id,but honestly I do not understand that variables have to put them, because in the end I have to convey to all, the variable Contatore.
Definitely are wrong variables that I wrote, because I can not convey anything

Comment: The thing is, if tabellone.js as described here is your whole node.js source file for the server: there is an error there. Because `contatore` on line 12 is not defined nor initialized somewhere.
Doesn't it throw an error ?

Comment: You 're right , it is not initialized .But then inside <code>io.on('connection',function(socket){ //here what? });</code>What should I write for convey the counter increases at all? ps. I can not enter correttamete tags for code

Answer (score -1):

Which is the code to trasmit the element, in this case that is

> contatore
>   I do not know what to put in the

```
 io.on('connection',function(socket){ //here what? });
```

I do not know how the insert of the fuction works